# nginx proxy manager on oracle cloud 502 Bad Gateway

Tags: nginx, docker-compose, oracle-cloud-infrastructure, jwilder-nginx-proxy

So I have ubuntu with docker-compose instance on oracle cloud

1. container nginx proxy manager

```
version: "3"
services:
  app:
    image: 'jc21/nginx-proxy-manager:latest'
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
      - '80:80' # Public HTTP Port
      - '443:443' # Public HTTPS Port
      - '81:81' # Admin Web Port
    environment:
      DISABLE_IPV6: 'true'
    volumes:
      - ./data:/data
      - ./letsencrypt:/etc/letsencrypt
```

2nd container website

```
version: '3'
services:
  app:
    image: 'nginx:latest'
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
      - '91:80'
    volumes:
      - ./data:/usr/share/nginx/html
```

sudo iptables -L INPUT -n --line-numbers
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
num  target     prot opt source               destination
1    ACCEPT     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            state RELATED,ESTABLISHED
2    ACCEPT     icmp --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
3    ACCEPT     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
4    ACCEPT     udp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            udp spt:123
5    ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            state NEW tcp dpt:22
6    REJECT     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-host-prohibited

nothing heavy!
If go by domain its showing "502 Bad Gateway",
but by ip:91 its working fine
somebody have experience how to solve?

i no have idea what need to do

Thank you for you time!

Comment: you need to provide more info  as a general rule the more clear info you provide the more likely u r to get help. U r mapping port 91 on the host to port 80 in docker, is the domain request coning from the internet on port 91?  in this case you will need a Internet Gateway in your VN, sec list or nsg entries for port 91 and also IP INPUT table rules for port 91, what is the output of  'sudo  iptables -L INPUT -n --line-numbers' ?  you will need to see something like "ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:91"

Comment: Oh sorry Nigel.

Comment: your rule line 3  "ACCEPT all -- 0.0.0.0/0 0.0.0.0/0" should let the packets thru on 91, now you should make sure your VN and sec lists and or nsg have an internet gateway and the corresponding rules for port 91, by the way the line 3 is not really a good idea